# Fastest Algorithm For Solving a Maze

Tags: algorithm, sorting, dijkstra, depth-first-search, maze

Lets say you are given a maze. For example:

```
#  ########
#    #    #
# #### #  #
# #    #  #
# #  # ####
#   #  #  #
# ###  ## #
#   #     #
#######   #
```

You can represent the maze in terms of any data structure you like, such as a graph, an array, etc.
What would be the fastest/ most efficient algorithm for solving a maze of any arbitrary size?

The algorithms that first come to mind are Dijkstra's algorithm, BFS, and DFS. I'm not sure which these (or any other algorithms) would be "best" though.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For maze problems like the above the most widely used algorithm is A* algorithm which visits adjacent nodes is an optimal manner and hence prevents visiting all the graph. You can use manhattan distance as heuristics for the problem and solve this problem very effficiently.

[A* Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

Since all the adjacent vertex are at distance 1 from each other so DFS would be best.

**nxm is the size of the array matrix**

```
 public static int min(int x , int y ,int endx,int endy,int n ,int m,int[][] dp){
         int[] dirx ={1,-1,0,0 };
            int[] diry={0,0,1,-1};
            LinkedList<Point> s = new LinkedList<Point>();
            s.add(new Point(x,y));
           dp[x][y]=0;  // For starting point

            while(!s.isEmpty()){
              Point xx = s.pop();
              for(int i=0;i<4;i++){

                  int x1 =  xx.x + dirx[i];
                  int y1  = xx.y + diry[i];

                  if(x1>=0 && x1<n && y1>=0 && y1<m && dp[x1][y1]!=-1){


                          som.add(new Point(x1,y1));
                          dp[x1][y1] = dp[xx.x][xx.y]+1;

                      }

                  }
              }





        return dp[endx][endy];
    }
```